# Case sensitive query Idiorm/SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, idiorm

I am having problems in finding anything like this in the Idiorm documentation. I am trying to do a case sensitive search something like :

```
$article=ORM::for_table('articles')->where_like('content','%fOo%')->find_many();
```

But i want the search to be case sensitive, what do i need to configure ?

LE: Here is how the table is defined:

```
ORM::get_db()->exec( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pw_article' );
     ORM::get_db()->exec(
    'CREATE TABLE pw_article(' .
    'art_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ' .
    'art_title TEXT, ' .
    'art_content TEXT, ' .
    'art_views INTEGER, ' .
    'art_publish_date DATETIME, ' .
    'art_update_date DATETIME, ' .
    'art_author INTEGER, ' .
    'FOREIGN KEY (art_author) REFERENCES pw_user (usr_id))'
);
```

Comment: How is that `content` column defined? More specifically, what's its `collation`?

Comment: I editet my post with the table definition.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, no ci collation here. Ok, what happens when you try `->where_raw("content LIKE BINARY '%fOo%'")` (instead of `where_like`)?

Comment: it gives me the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "'%fOo%'": syntax error' in C:\wamp\www\Scripts\idiorm.php on line 409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIKE operator always use case-insensitive comparisons.
(The column's collation does not affect this.)

To make such comparison case sensitive, either

- execute [PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = on;](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like) or
- replace LIKE with [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

  ```
  ->where_raw("content GLOB '*fOo*'")
  ```

Comment: Yes , it works perfectly. One more question, is it possible to add two fields where it can look in the same query ? I mean search for that string in content and title, and find it at least in one of them.

Comment: On the off chance someone comes across this same question , I'll add it here myself. In order to search 2 columns in the same raw query you can do the following: ->where_raw("column1 GLOB '*fOo*' OR column2 GLOB '*fOo*'")